# Using np.where with multiple conditions on Python Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I have home and away strings columns with football team and scorehome and scoreaway integer columns with the scores

I'd like to determinate with these values if the football match between two teams finished with the home victory ('1'), draw ('X'), or away victory ('2')

I tried np.where for every option, but I didn't find a good solution.

I will explain it better with my code.

This is my full code:

```
from typing import Generator    
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


matchlink = "https://www.betexplorer.com/football/england/national-league/results/"


def _get_rows(url: str) -> Generator[dict[str, str], None, None]:
    session = HTMLSession()

    r = session.get(matchlink)

    allmatch = r.html.find(".in-match")
    results = r.html.find(".h-text-center a")
    # search for elements containing "data-odd" attribute
    matchodds = r.html.find("[data-odd]")

    odds = [matchodd.attrs["data-odd"] for matchodd in matchodds]

    idx = 0
    for match, res in zip(allmatch, results):
        if res.text == "POSTP.":
            continue

        print(f"{match.text} Z {res.text} {', '.join(odds[idx:idx+3])}")
        yield {
            "match": match.text,
            "result": res.text,
            "odds": ", ".join(odds[idx : idx + 3]),
            "odds1": (odds[idx]), "odds2": (odds[idx+1]), "odds3": (odds[idx+2]),
        }

        idx += 3


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame(_get_rows(matchlink))#.set_index("match")
    df[['home','away']] = df['match'].str.split("-",expand=True) 
    df[['scorehome','scoreaway']] = df['result'].str.split(":",expand=True) 
    df = df.astype({'scorehome':'int'})
    df = df.astype({'scoreaway':'int'})
    cols = ['scorehome', 'scoreaway']
    df['sum_stats'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1, numeric_only=True)
    df['over05'] = np.where(df['sum_stats']>0, 'OK', 'NO')
    df['over15'] = np.where(df['sum_stats']>1, 'OK', 'NO')
    df['over25'] = np.where(df['sum_stats']>2, 'OK', 'NO')
    df['over35'] = np.where(df['sum_stats']>3, 'OK', 'NO')
    df['over45'] = np.where(df['sum_stats']>4, 'OK', 'NO')
    df['goal'] = np.where((df['scorehome'] >= 1) & 
         (df['scoreaway'] >= 1), 'OK', 'NO')
    df['final'] = np.where((df['scorehome'] > df['scoreaway'])
                     , '1', '')
    df['final'] = np.where((df['scorehome'] < df['scoreaway'])
                     , '2', '')
    df['final'] = np.where((df['scorehome'] == df['scoreaway'])
                     , 'X', '')
    df['result'] = df['result'].str.replace(':','-')
    df = df[['home','away','scorehome','scoreaway','result','odds1','odds2','odds3', 'sum_stats', 'over05', 'over15', 'over25', 'over35', 'over45', 'goal', 'final']]
    df = df.sort_values('odds1')

    print(df)


# determining the name of the file
file_name = 'BexData.xlsx'
 
# saving the excel
df.to_excel(file_name)
print('DataFrame is written to Excel File successfully.')
```

This code works well, except for this part:

```
df['final'] = np.where((df['scorehome'] > df['scoreaway'])
                 , '1', '')
df['final'] = np.where((df['scorehome'] < df['scoreaway'])
                 , '2', '')
df['final'] = np.where((df['scorehome'] == df['scoreaway'])
                 , 'X', '')
```

in this part, last np.where overwrite the first and second

My goal is to have something like this:

> if scorehome > scoreaway, final is 1; else  if scorehome < scoreaway,final is 2;  else if scorehome == scoreaway, final is X

I tried many solution, but I didn't got what I'd like to have

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be achieved by the following list comphrension:

```
df['final'] = [ '1' if score_home > score_away else '2' if score_home < score_away else 'X' 
               for score_home, score_away in zip(df['scorehome'], df['scoreaway'])]
```

Comment: I used your solution, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In this case one of the possible solutions is to use `apply` method and pass a function to it. Here is the equivalent function for what you said :

```
def final_status(row):
    if row['scorehome']>row['scoreaway']:
        return '1'
    elif row['scorehome']<row['scoreaway']:
        return '2'
    elif row['scorehome']==row['scoreaway']:
        return 'X'
    else:
        return ''
```

Now that you have this function, you can pass it to `apply` function for creating a new column :

```
df['final'] = df.apply(final_status,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than np.where which clearly replaces values according to True/False in each condition you can use np.select which is intended for just this scenario:

```
cond1 = df['scorehome'] > df['scoreaway']
cond2 = df['scorehome'] < df['scoreaway']
cond3 = df['scorehome'] == df['scoreaway']

df['final']= np.select([cond1, cond2, cond3], ['1', '2', 'X'])
```